# how to insert a column between 2 columns in a file?

Tags: macos, awk

I'm on Mac. Need to insert a column from file 1 to file 2 that has 4 columns. The inserted column will be between column 1 and 2 in file 2.

can I use "paste", but how to tell it to insert into a specific position?

Comment: Can you give us some sample data, the work you've done so far, an description of how it fails, and an example of the output you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
paste <(awk '{print $1}' file2) file1 <(awk '{print $2, $3, $4}' file2)
```

This creates three 'files', one with column 1 of `file2`, then `file1`, then columns 2-4 of `file2`, and uses `paste` to collect them together.  The `<(...)` notation is [Process Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution).

Answer (score 1):

You can like this:

```
echo "col1 col3 col4" | awk '{print $1,"col2",$2,$3}'
```

Depending on your delimiter between columns, you can easily modify it accordingly.

Comment: I admit the question lacks detail, but it sounds like they want to grab the column values from file 1 and insert them in file 2, rather than a fixed value? (To @user2228325 you should add some details like fish asked...)